# Kotlin - Passar dados entre Fragments

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, viewmodel

Estou com um problema numa aplicação que estou a desenhar.
Tenho 3 Fragments ( F1, F2, e F3):

- No F1 (*contém uma list com uma serie de desportos*) o utilizador faz a escolha relativamente a um desporto (utilizo um RecycleView  para isto).
- No F2 (*contém uma list com uma serie de espaços*) o utilizar escolhe o espaço ( utilizo também um RecycleView)

A questão é que no F3 quero "resumir" as escolhas do utilizador( *Desporto selecionado, espaço selecionado*).

A minha questão é qual e a forma mais eficiente de passar estes argumentos entre os 3 fragments?! SharedViewMOdel ou utilizado o SafeArgs?!
Ja tentei utilizar o SharedViewModel mas no F3 a variavel vai sempre a null.

```
   override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.itemview.text=listsports[position]

holder.itemview.setOnClickListener{

val sViewModel=SharedViewModel()

sViewModel.setSport(adapterposition)

v:View->v.findNavcontroller().navigate(R.id.action_F1_to_F2)}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conforme recomendado pela google, melhor usar SafeArgs para fazer essa tarefa.

Dentro do seu código ficaria algo assim:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.itemview.text=listsports[position]

    holder.itemview.setOnClickListener{

        val sport = listsports[position]

        val navegarF2 = F1Directions.actionF1toF2(sport)
        v:View->v.findNavcontroller().navigate(navegarF2)
    }
}
```

Será necessário declarar o tipo de dado que está passando entre os fragmentos, se precisar passar algum tipo de objeto é necessário que a classe do mesmo extenda Parcelable e de alt+enter na classe que será gerado automaticamente a implementação.

Se fosse passar uma suposta classe "sports" com 3 parametros, com parcelable ficaria assim:

```
clas Sports(val nome: String?, val time: String?, val jogadores: ArrayList<String>?): Parcelable {
constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(
    parcel.readString(),
    parcel.readString(),
    parcel.createStringArrayList()) {
}

override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
    parcel.writeString(nome)
    parcel.writeString(time)
    parcel.writeStringList(jogadores)
}

override fun describeContents(): Int {
    return 0
}

companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<sports> {
    override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): sports {
        return sports(parcel)
    }

    override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<sports?> {
        return arrayOfNulls(size)
    }
}
```

Lembrando que todo código dentro do {..} foi gerado automaticamente.

Documentação:
https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data?hl=pt-br
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable